# Can't install ElementaryOS on Framework

Tags: software-installation, iso

Good evening,

I am relatively inexperienced with Linux and have only used Ubuntu for a random Minecraft server so I apologize in advance if this is a stupid question, but I can't seem to get ElementaryOS to download on my Framework laptop. I've used multiple thumb drives, tried downloading the iso multiple times, and doing anything else but I always get the same issue every time. I boot into the setup screen, it loads stuff up for a bit, and I get a full blackscreen terminal with the following:

```
elementary OS Next elementary tty1

elementary login: [     62.809801] iwlwifi 000:a6:00.0: Timeout waiting for PVNM load!
[     62.809863] iwlwifi 000:a6:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[     62.809911] iwlwifi 000:a6:00.0: iwl_trans_send_cmd bad state = 1
[     63.013819]iwlwifi 000:a6:00.0: firmware didn't ACK the reset - continue anyway
[     63.026049]iwlwifi 000:a6:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

Nothing I do seems to make it work. I am using Etcher, as the ElementaryOS page recommends, and formatting the thumb drive itself doesn't give any issues. Please help

Comment: I would suggest reaching out to Framework if all else fails. This seems like a hardware / driver compatibility issue, and they should also value your feedback, as you're testing their laptops in the wild.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be booting into a tty session (#1) instead of the intended graphical session. You should be able to switch with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> to reach the login screen. Hopefully logging in and updating will fix this problem so it does not happen every time.